# Partially restore model in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have 2 models, whose architectures differ only in the last FC layer. My question is: how can I initialize the weights of the second model with the weights learned for the first model (without explicitly passing every variable's name (except the variables of the last FC layer) to the saver.restore)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial on tensorflow answers your problem : https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html